# sed with text and multiple delimiters

Tags: awk, sed

I am using sed to remove some text and replace it, I can get most of it accomplished but I'm at a stand still with replacing the string of 5 colon's before and the one after of it.  Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

*****Text file I have:*****

```
The user name1 ONE:TWO:THREE:FOUR:FIVE:NewName:SIX
The user name2 SEVEN:EIGHT:NINE:TEN:ELEVEN:NewName:TWELVE
The user name3 Thirteen:Fourteen:Fifteen:Sixteen:NewName:Seventeen
```

command:

```
sed 's/^/ The user /'| sed 's/:.*/ My New Name is/'
```

**Output:**

```
The user name1 My New Name is
```

**Expected output:**

```
The user name1 My New Name is NewName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed '/^The user / s/[^: ]*:.*:\(.*\):.*/My New Name is \1/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gs84pe):

```sh
s='The user name1 ONE:TWO:THREE:FOUR:FIVE:NewName:SIX
The user name2 SEVEN:EIGHT:NINE:TEN:ELEVEN:NewName:TWELVE
The user name3 Thirteen:Fourteen:Fifteen:Sixteen:NewName:Seventeen'
sed '/^The user / s/[^: ]*:.*:\(.*\):.*/ My New Name is \1/' <<< "$s"
# => 
#    The user name1 My New Name is NewName
#    The user name2 My New Name is NewName
#    The user name3 My New Name is NewName
```

Here,

- `/^The user /` - finds the lines that start with `The user`
- `s/[^: ]*:.*:\(.*\):.*/ My New Name is \1/` finds

  - `[^: ]*` - zero or more chars other than a colon and space
  - `:.*:` - `:`, any text, `:`
  - `\(.*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any text
  - `:.*` - `:` and the rest of the string.
- `\1` is the replacement placeholder, the contents of Group 1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that is what I was missing to better understand sed and what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use `awk`:

```sh
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, "My New Name is", a[split($NF, a, /:/)-1]}' file

The user name1 My New Name is NewName
The user name2 My New Name is NewName
The user name3 My New Name is NewName
```

Comment: `awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $1, $2, $3, "My New Name is", $(NF-1)}' file` should also work

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following.

```
awk -F'[ :]' '{print $1,$2,$3,"My New Name is",$(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as space OR colon here for all lines. Then simply printing 1st, 2nd, 3rd fields followed by string `May Name is` followed by 2nd last field of current line as per requirements of OP.